# dash dropdown callback not working with multiple outputs

Tags: python, plotly-dash

[the interface of the dashboard]
I'am using dashes to create a dashboard, I have a drop-down and I want that whenever I change the option all the groups in my dashboroard change, the code works fine with one output (one figure), but when I try to use multiple outputs in the callback function, all the callback functions stop working.

[image: 1]

This code works, the figure here is a button, when I try multiple outputs it fails, no error message

```
@ app.callback(
        Output("btn-nclicks-1", "figure"),
        [Input(component_id='dropdown', component_property='value')],
    )
    def update_charts(value):
        global filtered_data2
        if "btn-nclicks-1" != ctx.triggered_id:
            print("pressed------------------------")

            filtered_data2 = data.loc[(data.ID_PUIT == value)]
            #query("ID_PUIT == 'value")
            pd.DataFrame(filtered_data2)
            # iwill filter my data according to the value attribute
            print(filtered_data2, value)

        price_chart_figure = {"data": [{
            "x": filtered_data2["START_DATE"],
            "y": filtered_data2["PROD"],
            "type": "lines",
            "hovertemplate": "%{y:.2f}<extra></extra>", }, ],
            "layout": {"title": "production jugage"},
        }

        return price_chart_figure
```

Comment: Can you share the code when you try multiple outputs? Also, try looking in the browser console for an error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

i think the problem was the following: I have two callback functions with the same outputs but different inputs, so what I did was I kept the call back function and added a new input, in this case, the dropdown. insted of

` @ app.callback1(

```
[Output("C", "figure"),Output("D", "figure")
[Input("A", "start_date"),
 Input("B", "end_date")],)
```

@ app.callback2(

```
Output("C", "figure"),
[Input("E", "start_date"),)  `
```

the solution for me was to use :

@app.callback([Output("C", "figure")], [Input("A", "start_date"),
Input("B", "end_date"),Input("E", "start_date")],)